# Scanning for digital cable on me-tv

Tags: linux, tv

I have a pinnacle pchd 800 USB tuner that I want to use with Me-TV. I can't figure how to get it to scan for digital clear cam channels though, I've tried the standard cable frequency option and it didn't get anything. I'm in the U.S. and have Time Warner cable.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the "PCTV HD Pro Stick"?  The 800 models I can find are not USB.

The USB "PCTV HD Pro Stick" does not list CLEARQAM in its specifications.